# I there a proven way to handle update intervals with automatic trigger check/installation and multiple users between multiple spreadsheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm working on an addon that needs to update spreadsheets in user specified intervals (from once an hour to once a year) - is there a smart, proven way to handle that with automatic trigger check/installation and multiple users between multiple spreadsheets?

From what I understand the triggers are installed individually per user - can anyone reveal the mystery behind how the time-driven triggers for add-ons work in the following cases?

1. The check whether triggers are installed doesn't 'see' if it's been been installed by other users and it can't manipulate it (eg. delete someone else's trigger when no longer needed). Any ideas on how to cope with that? Having 50 users with installed hourly triggers is not ideal.
2. Multiple spreadsheets with the addon installed: will the trigger run the called function in all of them simultaneously or do they require individual triggers per sheet? Dry testing seems to indicate that the triggers need to be set up individually per sheet, though would be great if someone could confirm their experience from an add-on that's already online.

In order to control a potential chaos I'm considering adding a 'last updated' property to scheduled update instances and have the triggered function compare the time difference between that and current time, but then it's still going back to having that function run every hour multiplied by the amount of users.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. The question is primarily opinion-based, needs more focus, it lacks of a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask]. Please [edit] the question to narrow it's scope, make it specific and answerable.

Answer (score 2):

*will the trigger run the called function in all of them simultaneously or do they require individual triggers per sheet?*

[Installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#g_suite_application_triggers) are installed per [sheet | document | form] per [user] (well, to be precise, per *script project*). Given the fact that they are isolated for each user, they are also triggered respective to each user (as opposed to simple triggers).

**Installable onOpen | onEdit | onChange**

There is a case, though, where this might not be as easy - see installable [`onOpen`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions) triggers section in official guide. Although the general case still holds - even if the other account will trigger it, the trigger will be run **against creator's account**, which includes quotas and everything user-related, so be extra careful with that.

*Any ideas on how to cope with that?*

Although [installable] triggers are not shared across users, some resources are shared between them, so you have at least two possible ways to deal with concurrent triggers firing:

1. Preferred way: [`LockService`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock-service). It is specifically designed to avoid race conditions such as your case: just wait (or reschedule if the action might take more than 5 minutes) until the lock can be aqcuired (note that you need to use a script or document lock).
2. Fallback way: if you intend to let users concurrently interact with the UI, the lock will fail (by design). You had a right idea of using `PropertiesService` (I assume that this is what you meant by "adding a property"), but beware that reads / writes are subject to [quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).

   I recently answered a similar question - it has a working and tested [sample of emulating](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62195747/11407695) `LockService` behaviour with `PropertiesService` (but again, be careful with quotas).

**Notes**

You have to be aware of the [problem with time-based](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62264863/11407695) triggers and account for that (also the referred answer contians a simpler to implement solution for checking the timestamp).